# Validate the Phone 10 digit number in the pop up and prevent from being submitted if less than 10

Tags: javascript

You can see the test form: https://dtreacy.lpages.co/test-1/ on the pop up (Click "Get Started to open").
SO far, I have been able to input the mask with the following:

```
document.getElementById('06fc37a3bf5a6575096f513ba758203a-53SMSEbA4DKdUs7QEJBsZV').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
  e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
});
```

What I am looking for is to prevent the form being submitted if the phone number is not 10 digit.

Comment: if (value.length < 10) return

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447930/validation-for-10-digit-mobile-number-and-focus-input-field-on-invalid/24261301

Comment: I have reviewed the common SO answers. I have no control over the form tag, so I can't add pattern attribute , an ID can't be added to the form tag.

Answer (score 0):

Make the type of button as button instead of submit and submit the form through js
like

```
if(e.target.value.length < 10){
    alert('fail')
}else{
  // submit form through js
}
```

Set the id of form and follow this tutorial [How to submit form through Javascript](http://javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml)

Comment: It does not prevent the form being submitted.

Comment: i updated the answer please have a look and if it solved your problem mark it solved for others

Comment: Setting an ID is not an option. We are using a 3rd party page builder.

Comment: Then just use document.forms[0].submit() directly and check that if it worked or not also you can access form by parent property of js